# Uncaught Autodesk\Forge\Client\ApiException: [504] Error connecting to the API phpSDK

Tags: php, autodesk-forge

I have already used
from:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
```

to:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, file_get_contents($postData));
```

and also tried to add

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING , "");
```

can anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using the source code from [this repo](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/learn.forge.viewmodels/tree/php), it uses `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);`

Now if you're having trouble with one specific request, please add that to your question.